# How to make sub clumps for geometry nodes based hair

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

In nature, hair often forms in clumps, however, often these clumps are made up of other clumps, if you want to make convincing animal fur you need to replicate this behavior. However I can't seem to get the geometry nodes setup correct. Here is my current setup
[image] and you can see I modified the hair clump modifier (probably where I messed up) so that I can pass in the guide curves to use (which as you can see, it uses the closest curve from the low density interpolation as the guide curve)
[image]
However, this gives terrible results, the hair curves are overlapping, which, if it was working correctly, you'd expect to see a Voronoi shaped bald spots between the sub clumps.  [image]

I decided to investigate further by making a setup that allowed me to render only one sub clump at the time, and you can see that some of the hair curves aren't even on the surface! the most normal looking index is index 0, but as I increase the index number the sub clumps get more and more glitchy looking
[image: Index 0]
[image: Index 7]

If you'd like to see intended results, this video is a great reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kJj1W9gGrA

Comment: Why don't you use the asset nodes groups that come with Blender 3.5? There is a [tutorial video from Blender](https://youtu.be/_-d0HaT5f1g?feature=shared) and a [demo file with examples of different fur types](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/#hair).

Comment: @Blunder I am, that's what the clump node is. but I need to make sub clumps that build up clumps, and to my knowledge none of the asset node groups can do that for me

Comment: @Blunder Oh, but you are right that demo file has my answer, apparently you can just pass a clump node into another clump node? i really have no clue why that works and it would be nice to be able to have more control over each clump (like shortening specific sub clumps and such)